# Passing a Map from Java to Kotlin does not compile when updating the map

Tags: kotlin, hashmap, kotlin-java-interop

I have a Java function that has a `Map<String, String` and needs to pass it to a Kotlin function for adding values to the map.
The problem is that if I have:

```
fun updateMap(map: Map<String, String>)
```

It seems that the `map` is immutable and I can't do: `map[KEY] = VALUE` as I get compilation error.
It would work if I did: `fun updateMap(map: HashMap<String, String>)` but in that case I can't pass the original `map` from the Java code without some casting which I would like to avoid if possible.
What is the solution for this?

Comment: `Map` is immutable in kotlin, if you want a mutable map then it's `MutableMap`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin, unlike Java, has separate interfaces for mutable and read-only collections, see [Kotlin Collections Overview](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections-overview.html).

The `Map` interface in Kotlin doesn't expose any modifying functions (including the operator `map[key] = value`), but `MutableMap` does.

On the JVM, the Kotlin `Map` and `MutableMap` interfaces are both represented by the `java.util.Map`, so you can freely change your parameter type to `MutableMap<String, String>`:

```
fun updateMap(map: MutableMap<String, String>) {
    map["foo"] = "bar"
}
```

Note that you might need to change `Map` to `MutableMap` in some other places in your Kotlin code, as the compiler won't allow you to pass a read-only `Map` as a `MutableMap` argument.

As for `HashMap`, given that it's a concrete implementation, it also implements the `MutableMap` and therefore exposes the mutating functions. However, using interfaces and not implementation classes is more preferable.

Comment: What if that was `<String, Object>` in Java?

Comment: Replace `Object` with `Any` (or, `Any?`, if nullable values are allowed, though in `Map`s they should not be used), that's the Kotlin equivalent of the supertype to all types.